# No mostrar warnings ni notice NPM

Tags: npm, docker

Estoy corriendo el siguiente dockerfile

```
    # etapa de compilación
FROM node:current-buster-slim as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# etapa de producción
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Al momento de que corre el NPM RUN INSTALL y el NPM RUN BUILD me salen algunos warnings y notice.
¿Como puedo evitar que esos mensajes salgan en los logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nivel de aplicación [`npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config) puedes:

```
npm install --silent
```

A nivel de [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) puedes:

```
docker build [...] --quiet
```

Pero este último será para todo el `build` entero.